# VBS - how to get today's date of a file name?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I got a program to convert .csv to .xls file but the files has today's date in it name, for example "C:\Users\user\Downloads\arquivo_2019-02-19.csv", then when i need to convert it's necessary to change, for every file, in vbs code (in the end of this message).

I have a function that a use in another example, i'm putting here just to describe how it could be.

```
    %let todaysDate = %sysfunc(today(), yymmdd10.); 
filename  test1 ftp "C:\Users\user\Downloads\arquivo_&todaysdate..csv"
```

**How can i automate this process for code to get today's date for each new file?**

```
Option Explicit

Dim fldr, f, file,strOrigFile, strFile, fso, strDirectory
Dim objExcel

strOrigFile = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\arquivo_2019-02-19.csv"  
'******************************************************
'CONVERTS THE FILE TO AN EXCEL FILE
'******************************************************
strFile = replace(strOrigFile,".csv",".xls")

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open strOrigFile

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFile, -4143

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit

'******************************************************
'FORMAT THE EXCEL FILE AND SAVE IT
'******************************************************

objExcel.Workbooks.Open strFile

objExcel.columns("A:A").numberformat="0"
objExcel.columns("C:C").numberformat="0"


objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFile, -4143

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

msgbox "FINISHED!!!"
```

Comment: [Use `NOW()`](https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-now-function.html)?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fldr, f, file,strOrigFile, strFile, fso, strDirectory
Dim objExcel
Dim dd, mm, yy
Dim datevalue, timevalue, dtsnow, dtsvalue

dtsnow = Now()
dd = Right("00" & Day(dtsnow), 2)
mm = Right("00" & Month(dtsnow), 2)
yy = Year(dtsnow)

datevalue = yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd

strOrigFile = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\arquivo_" & datevalue & ".csv"

'******************************************************
'CONVERTS THE FILE TO AN EXCEL FILE
'******************************************************
strFile = replace(strOrigFile,".csv",".xls")

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open strOrigFile

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFile, -4143

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit

'******************************************************
'FORMAT THE EXCEL FILE AND SAVE IT
'******************************************************

objExcel.Workbooks.Open strFile

objExcel.columns("A:A").numberformat="0"
objExcel.columns("C:C").numberformat="0"

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFile, -4143

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

msgbox "FINISHED!!!"
```

Comment: Please explain why this is an answer to this question

Comment: As described above the problem is related to today's date in the file name, the script below solves the problem by calculating the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD and the postpone after the file name